# The relationship of integral and differential

Tags: derivatives

I am new to integral and I am confused by something why is the formula of integral 
∫f(x)dx = F(x)+c 
If f(x)=F'(x) 
But not 
∫f(x)=F(x)+c 
As I know derivative and differential are two different things
In the first one it is actually the integral of differential of F(x) rather than derivative of F(x) then why we say derivative and integral are inverse rather than saying differential and integral are inverse of each other?

Answer (score 0):

The differential notation comes from the concept of the Riemman integral, rather than just obtaining the function for which you took the derivative of, it represents the sum of infinitely many areas over an interval $I$.

Suppose you have a function $f(x)= F'(x)$ that is continuous over an interval $a≤x≤b=I$.
To get the area of the function in this interval, you can use rectangles with base $Δx$ and height $f(x_k)$ where $k∈I$, how accurate this area is depends in how many rectangles you create on $I$, the concept of the Riemman integral is that you arrive at the value of the area by adding infinitely many rectangles over this interval, so let's make infinitely many bases on $I$ where all bases $Δx$ are equal to each other.
$$Δx=\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{b-a}{n}$$
Let $x_k=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_k)$ be an arithmetic sequence where $x_k∈I$ and $x_1≤x_2≤x_3≤...≤x_k$, if we sum each $x_k$ evaluated on $f(x)$ and multiply it by $Δx$, we get the area of the function on the interval $I$, thus: 
$$Area=\lim_{n\to ∞}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)Δx=\lim_{n\to ∞}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$
This is the concept of the Riemann integral. 
$$\lim_{n\to ∞}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)Δx=\int_a^b{f(x)dx}$$
So you see the differential has a meaning that shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: The definite integral $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ depends only on function $f$ and interval $[a, b] $. The $x$ and $dx$ are only a part of notation like $\int$. Also the way you write $\Delta x$ as a limit it is $0$. In the usual analysis/calculus these symbols like $dx$ are used for technical convenience as well as historical reasons.

Comment: Also one adds only finitely many rectangles. The idea is that approximation of area using such sums gets better if number of rectangles increases. This is like measuring a length by a ruler. If the unit markers on ruler are of small size then the measurement is more accurate.